# How to make a header value router in spring integration java dsl and assign it a default output channel?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have it like this currently:

```
.route("headers.STATE", new Consumer<RouterSpec<ExpressionEvaluatingRouter>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(RouterSpec<ExpressionEvaluatingRouter> spec) {
            spec
                .channelMapping(ProcStatus.NORMAL_OPERATION.toString(), "primaryChannel")
                .channelMapping(ProcStatus.FAILED_OVER.toString(), "secondaryChannel")
                .channelMapping(ProcStatus.UNKNOWN.toString(), "stateRetrievalChannel");
                }
            })
```

But it's not really a header value router per se right? I can't seem to set HeaderValueRouter as the routing spec and just give the name of the header on the first param.

Plus i couldn't find a default channel mapping on the spec. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest the `<header-value-router>` does not make sense since introduction of `SpEL` router, where you can simply configure it like `expression="headers.STATE"`, like in your config for Java DSL.

Everything else is the same for any kind of `Router` implementation.
See more in the [reference manual](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#routers).

And, yes, you can use `HeaderValueRouter` directly as well:

```
.route(new HeaderValueRouter("STATE"), new Consumer<RouterSpec<ExpressionEvaluatingRouter>>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(RouterSpec<ExpressionEvaluatingRouter> spec) {
        spec
            .channelMapping(ProcStatus.NORMAL_OPERATION.toString(), "primaryChannel")
            .channelMapping(ProcStatus.FAILED_OVER.toString(), "secondaryChannel")
            .channelMapping(ProcStatus.UNKNOWN.toString(), "stateRetrievalChannel");
            }
        })
```

But as you see the `.channelMapping()` remains the same.

As for "default channel mapping". I think you just mean `default-output-channel`, which we have in the XML configuration.

If you noticed no one component in the SI Java DSL has an `output-channel` option (the `default-output-channel` plays the same role). We just propagate the next `.channel()` definition in the `IntegrationFlow` to the current `outputChannel`-aware component. So, to map the `default-output-channel` for the `.route()` you should just go ahead in the method-chain with the `IntegrationFlow` definition. Like this:

```
.route()
.handle()
```

So, if routing condition doesn't meet any `.channelMapping()` and `resolutionRequired == false`, the message will be send to the next `.handle()` through the implicit `DirectChannel` between them.

Comment: Oh cool. I did try adding to the chain but i didn't know about the bool, thanks. The reference mentioned there's native support for header value router which kinda got me confused since the one in the dsl is a content based one. But i guess it was talking about spring integration rather than dsl specifically. Thanks for clarifying :)